# Input string not in correct format. Server only error

Tags: c#, xml

I'm getting an

> "Input string was not in a correct format"

error. Now normally this occurs when converting string to integers that are not valid etc, but I don't this applies here.

This only happens on a server the application has been deployed to, it does not happen when I take the XML and run it through on my development PC.

```
public XmlDocument AddStatusCodeToValidResponse(XmlDocument response)
{
    XmlElement httpStatusCode = response.CreateElement("HttpStatusCode");
    httpStatusCode.InnerText = "200 OK";

    XmlNamespaceManager xDocNs = new XmlNamespaceManager(response.NameTable);
    xDocNs.AddNamespace("ns", constNs);

    XmlNode rootNode = response.SelectSingleNode("//ns:Output", xDocNs);
    rootNode.AppendChild(httpStatusCode);

    return response;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what it could be?

EDIT: Callstack:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>      at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
>      at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
>      at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
>      at AddStatusCodeToValidResponse(XmlDocument response)

Comment: What is the call stack?

Comment: @AlexK. Call stack edit added :)

Comment: Did you try giving it just "200"?

Comment: My bet, the server uses different localization than your dev machine, that's why it only fails there. Change your localization to the same as the server and debug, it should fail and you will be able to see exactly where and why.

Comment: Do you happen to know which line it's actually failing on?

Comment: I have not yet tried just 200 because it works for me with the OK and no where is it specified as an integer. @Gusman What localization settings and where would I find these?

Comment: @RyanThomas Check the language, the date/time format and the numeric format: https://superuser.com/questions/969078/how-can-i-change-number-format-in-my-pc-windows-8

Comment: I know of no localisation that would affect simply setting the `InnerText` on an `XmlElement`...

Comment: Hmm. I've just rebuilt the .dll dropped it in and done an iisreset and appears to be working now. Can an admin put this on hold or something?